# TensorFlow benchmark on multiple threads killed

Tags: linux, tensorflow, benchmarking

Yesterday, I was running some perf tests using the Conda build of TensorFlow, i.e. TF v1.12:

```
conda create -n tf_conda python=3.6.8 tensorflow
git clone -b cnn_tf_v1.12_compatible --single-branch https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks.git
cd benchmarks/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/
conda activate tf_conda
python tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --device=cpu --model=resnet50 --data_format=NHWC --num_batches=10 --num_warmup_batches=1
```

Today, when I install TensorFlow with Conda, I end up with v1.13:

```
conda create -n tf_conda python=3.6.8 tensorflow
git clone -b cnn_tf_v1.13_compatible --single-branch https://github.com/tensorflow/benchmarks.git
cd benchmarks/scripts/tf_cnn_benchmarks/
conda activate tf_conda
python tf_cnn_benchmarks.py --device=cpu --model=resnet50 --data_format=NHWC --num_batches=10 --num_warmup_batches=1
```

However, the benchmark fails miserably:

```
2019-04-05 08:41:04.146441: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:141] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: SSE4.1 SSE4.2 AVX
2019-04-05 08:41:04.164798: I tensorflow/core/platform/profile_utils/cpu_utils.cc:94] CPU Frequency: 2599995000 Hz
2019-04-05 08:41:04.165499: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:150] XLA service 0x563d6af00290 executing computations on platform Host. Devices:
2019-04-05 08:41:04.165542: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:158]   StreamExecutor device (0): <undefined>, <undefined>
OMP: Info #212: KMP_AFFINITY: decoding x2APIC ids.
OMP: Info #213: KMP_AFFINITY: cpuid leaf 11 not supported - decoding legacy APIC ids.
OMP: Info #149: KMP_AFFINITY: Affinity capable, using global cpuid info
OMP: Info #154: KMP_AFFINITY: Initial OS proc set respected: 0-3
OMP: Info #156: KMP_AFFINITY: 4 available OS procs
OMP: Info #157: KMP_AFFINITY: Uniform topology
OMP: Info #159: KMP_AFFINITY: 4 packages x 1 cores/pkg x 1 threads/core (4 total cores)
OMP: Info #214: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc to physical thread map:
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 0 maps to package 0
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 1 maps to package 1
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 2 maps to package 2
OMP: Info #171: KMP_AFFINITY: OS proc 3 maps to package 3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 1539 tid 1539 thread 0 bound to OS proc set 0
2019-04-05 08:41:04.166391: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:71] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
W0405 08:41:04.172703 140193590863680 deprecation.py:323] From /home/nsapay/anaconda3/envs/tf_conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py:263: colocate_with (from tensorflow.python.framework.ops) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.
Instructions for updating:
Colocations handled automatically by placer.
...
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 1539 tid 1557 thread 1 bound to OS proc set 1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 1539 tid 1585 thread 3 bound to OS proc set 3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 1539 tid 1586 thread 4 bound to OS proc set 0
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 1539 tid 1584 thread 2 bound to OS proc set 2
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 1539 tid 1556 thread 5 bound to OS proc set 1
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 1539 tid 1588 thread 7 bound to OS proc set 3
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 1539 tid 1587 thread 6 bound to OS proc set 2
OMP: Info #250: KMP_AFFINITY: pid 1539 tid 1589 thread 8 bound to OS proc set 0
Killed.
```

I am completely puzzled... I did not update the system between yesterday and today. I am using 4 (virutal) cores (Intel Xeon E3), and a regular CentOS 7 distribution.

Comment: check your kernel log to see if the out-of-memory killer killed it.  (`dmesg | less` and search for OOM)

Comment: Indeed, I've got an out-of-memory error. That is unexpected as there is 7.3/7.5 GB available. Furthermore, I was able to perform the benchmark on a (physical) Windows machine, with similar hardware configuration. Could it be related to the virtualization?

Comment: There you go, then.  Your TensorFlow used so much memory that it triggered the OOM killer on your machine.  In theory you could add more swap space, but performance is typically unacceptable.  (That does let the kernel swap out things *other than* "hot" pages first, but there's probably not much other than tensorflow using memory.)

Comment: Thank you, I was trying to figure out what  would be a minimal tensorflow machine for the dev. I've got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, I was out of memory. The memory monitoring was from another virtual machine (the inconvenience of workinng with several machine at the same time).